# popBackStack in onPostExecute causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, illegalstateexception

Apologize this is a fairly long post, let me try to explain the background first:

I've read a lot of posts on this topic (and [Alex's excellent blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) on this topic), and the general conclusion seems to be not perform fragment transactions in an async callback (see [Dianne's post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/dXZZjhRjkMk/QybqCW5ukDwJ)), like `AsyncTask#onPostExecute()`.

However I have 2 cases where this is necessary:

1. An `Activity` showing a login `Fragment`, when user press the login button, an `AsyncTask` starts to authenticate with server, then when login success is returned, the login `Fragment` is replaced with the main app `Fragment`.
2. An `Activity` showing the main app fragment, when user triggers some action that requires logging in, a login fragment replaces the main fragment which is added to backstack. Again when the login button is pressed, `AsyncTask` authenticates with server, then when login succeeds, we want to pop backstack to reveal the main `Fragment` to the user and let them do the action they wanted to perform.

Case 1 can be solved by using `commitAllowingStateLoss`, but Case 2 is tricky as there is no such flavor of popBackStack in `FragmentManager`.

In any case, both of these cases require special handling of app going to background during `AsyncTask#doInBackground()`, causing `onPostExecute()` getting called when app is in background. One solution is to use Fragment.isResumed to guard replace fragment or pop backstack, and then handle process killed situation by logging in again or save some flag indicating a successful recent login and replace/pop the login fragment on app restore state (login `Fragment` is restored to top by `FragmentManager`). Or allow state loss, and handle process killed then restored situation, check recent login and remove the login fragment.

Is this how you would handle this? It feels like a lot of work just to handle a very common situation.

Comment: 'It feels like a lot of work just to handle a very common situation.'
Yes, you are right. I have same problems in one app. But as an alternative i can suggest you split main fragment and login fragment in activities. This will simplify handling transitions between this screens.

Comment: thanks, having another activity for login would solve this for the phone, but imagine a tablet 2 pane layout (nav pane and content pane) where login replaces the content pane as a fragment, can't use activities in this case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [x90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799799/x90) mentioned in the comment above, the easiest solution would be to split your fragments up into separate activities. This will obviously avoid the exception because launching a new activity doesn't require modifying the state of the previous activity. Swapping fragments in/out of the screen like this is probably not what you want to do anyway... as their names suggest, `Fragment`s were designed to serve as "fragments" of the user interface, and not as much as entire screens which make up the user interface. (Of course, I don't mean to suggest that you aren't *allowed* to use `Fragment`s in this way... I'm just saying that it wasn't a design goal of the `Fragment` API).

You could also try to implement some sort of cancellation policy in your `AsyncTask`. That is, if the activity ever begins to go into the background, cancel the task immediately. When the `AsyncTask` finally finishes, make sure that `isCancelled()` returns `false` before performing fragment transactions, etc.

Comment: Would starting activity after app is backgrounded (user press home button or say phone call comes in) make our activity the top activity?
I agree with the multiple activity solution for the phone, but I think fragments are still required for tablet layout, say we have a 2 pane tablet layout with nav and content pane, and the current content pane requires user logging in, so the login fragment replaces the content pane (or added on top of the content pane). In this case we want to dismiss the login fragment if login succeeded, instead of showing a dialog or a confirm button in the login fragmen

Comment: continued from comment above...
I agree with the cancellation policy solution. So in the case when the async callback succeeded, it needs to persist this fact in some way other than through the save instance state mechanism (say shared preference or database), then when the app is foregrounded, login fragment checks this persisted flag to see if login actually went through, and dismiss itself accordingly.

Comment: Thinking about it more, actually the async callback can just set a boolean flag field in the fragment, which can be checked in the fragment's onStart method, if set dismiss, otherwise normal.
Dismiss call in the fragment is guarded with isResumed (after app background this returns false).

Answer (score 6):

A more recent workaround is to call `FragmentActivity.onStateNotSaved()` before `popBackStack()`.

Comment: Interesting API, looks like it was introduced in API 23
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStateNotSaved()
But is generally available via the support library.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onStateNotSaved()

The intention of the Activity flavor sounds like it is meant to be a callback. But the support library FragmentActivity flavor can be called by client code that will actually modify fragment manager state saved flag, preventing the dreaded IllegalStateException ;)